# Displaying old Python version

Tags: python

My computer previously had Python 2.7. I recently installed Python 3.2. But when I run Python prompt from the Terminal, it still shows the version as 2.7.3.

```
dineshkumar@dineshkumar-desktop:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:46:21)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

How do I change it to 3.2?

Comment: Try checking out the answers to this question for some insight here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14615/how-do-i-make-the-terminal-run-python-3-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3.2 will be available as `python3.2`, or possibly `python3` depending on which version of Ubuntu you are using.

Significant parts of Ubuntu are written in python and you cannot change which version the `python` link points to without breaking the system. You can install extra versions, but you'll have to use a longer name to start them, eg `python3.3`, `python2.6`).

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315015/how-can-i-remove-python-2-7-after-installing-python-3-3) for more details.

The default python versions are:

```
Lucid/11.10        2.6.5    3.1.2
Precise/12.04      2.7.3    3.2.3
Quantal/12.10      2.7.3    3.2.3
Raring/13.04       2.7.4    3.3.1
```

Comment: Or `python3.3` on Ubuntu 13.04. `python3` should link to whatever version of Python 3.x you have installed.