# Python 3 installation

Tags: apt, python

I checked my system to see which Python is installed. I realized it was version 2.7.12. Than I downloaded the last version from Python.org which is 3.6.5. Now I have a tar.xz archive file that I extracted to somewhere (currently "Downloads" folder). Now what? What should I do? Which file should I double-click to install?

Note: I also tried `sudo apt-get install python3` which seemed to do things (commands running in terminal like in Matrix) but at the end when I rechecked the Python version it was the old 2.7.12 version.
Any suggestions?

Comment: try `which python` in terminal and see if it returns `/usr/bin/python` then do `which python3` and see if it returns `/usr/bin/python3` .. if so .. they are both installed .. my system has both .. if I want python3 .. I run `python3` command.

Comment: if I do `python --version` I get `Python 2.7.12` returned and if I do `python3 --version` I get `Python 3.5.2` returned ,,, not the "latest" but the latest for Ubuntu's install :D

Comment: oh .. sorry .. not a python guy so .. that was just a thought .. lol but sounds like its not look upon well ... :D I will remove the thought :D

Comment: DON'T UNINSTALL any Python versions that you will find with your Ubuntu installation, it will break your system. If you want the latest Python version take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-the-latest-python-2-7-x-or-3-x-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Please note that Python (both 2 and 3) are dependencies of important components of your Ubuntu system, like e.g. your package manager `apt` and many other things. You *really* don't want to mess your system up by removing one of these, setting them to an incorrect version (Python 2 and 3 are not compatible, one generally can't run scripts for the other without some adaption) or breaking them in any other way. Just search this site for questions of people who messed it up, you'll find many. Not few of them end with a system reinstall.

Comment: ahh yeah .. sorry didn't think of dependencies  yeah .. my thought would have trashed the system :D .. glad you were here to intervene :D

Comment: If anyone wants to use `python3` with `python` command its safe to use this command `echo alias python=python3 >> ~/.bash && source ~/.bashrc`. Just do it and **don't remove** or **symlink** `/usr/bin/python` at all!

Comment: yes thanks much better solution ... I jumped the gun and wasn't thinking of the consequences

Answer (score 1):

<s>The</s> One right way to install `python3` is

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

or

```
sudo apt install python3
```

Whether you use `apt` or `apt-get` doesn't matter in this case; it is just a personal habit. `apt` is a *front-end* for `apt-get` but for this command there's no difference, so both are fine.

Once installed you have the new command `python3`.

*Python* is somehow special in that there are two major versions: *python2* and *python3*. When you install or update (or call) `python` you'll get the *python2* line.

Some time ago the Python developers decided to release a completely new version of Python with new features and new syntax. To not break existing programs, this new version is called `python3`. So it's completely safe (and usual) to have both `python` (V2) and `python3` installed at the same time. Some of your existing programs will use `python` (V2) and some of them will use `python3`. The majority will currently use `python` (V2) (because they aren't rewritten yet to comply with python3's syntax), so do NOT uninstall `python` (V2).

See also [How can I remove python 2.7 after installing python 3.3?](https://askubuntu.com/q/315015/504066). The question is five years old but still valid. The outcome is **don't**!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have downloaded the source tar files, You have to use the `configure`, `make` and `make install` utilities. As demonstrated [here](http://www.ciscostuff.gurjap.org/how-to-install-python-in-different-directory-leaving-the-default-untouched/). Change to the extracted directory run those commands. you may leave the `--prefix` part if you want to replace the system's current installed Python version.